# Cannot find svn.exe on C# build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn

So I've checked out a project in svn using Tortoise(latest version), and whenever I build it I get the message "Cannot find svn.exe! Please make sure it's installed in your path". I don't know what's going on, as the other projects I have checked out aren't doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build probably uses the command-line SVN client somewhere in a custom build step.

Either remove that or install the command-line client.

Comment: @Fender, you might have to "grep" your *.csproj files to find this if you don't know where it is coming from.

Comment: Ended up just installing the command-line client for Tortoise, and that fixed the issue. Thanks!